# Laptop Accelerometers

Tags: accelerometer, touchsmart

I have an HP TouchSmart tablet. Are there any USB accelerometers that I can attach to the tablet and make it behave like the iPhone screen does when the device is turned?

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding. The answers are encouraging and I just need to find a small enough USB accelerometer to plug-in. Google search offers no leads, yet, on where I can buy one from.

Comment: You ask in particular for a USB accelerometer. Note that there are other options. (1) iBeacons with an accelerometer. In that case you'll need to make use of Bluetooth Low Energy to query for this type of data. Even better would be an iBeacon that adds accelerometer data to the advertisement frame (so you don't need to connect to it). (2) Transfer accelerometer data from your phone to your tablet. So to rotate your tablet you rotate your phone. Might be fun!

Answer (score -1):

Nope. For this to work, you would have to be using an operating system that supported accelerometers and AFAIK, only iPhone OS does.

Comment: nothing to do with the OS. for example, Firefox 3.6 supports accelerometers. http://www.downloadsquad.com/tag/accelerometer/

Comment: @Molly In that case, only Firefox would rotate. Your other applications would remain the same (unless they too supported accelerometers). If I understand the OP correctly, (s)he wants the whole screen to rotate.

Comment: plenty ways to rotate displays and input devices, it happens at driver level, i'm pretty sure the TouchSmart allows to rotate the display and input devices (manually). again, not depending on the OS :)

Comment: Molly is right, this is not specifically to do with the OS.  What it is to do with is the graphics card drivers (if you want full screen rotation i.e. monitors can be Portrait or Landscape, I have one of each at work), the applications (for application dependant, i.e. Firefox) and the actual sensor device.  There is no reason that you couldn't get an accelerometer type device and then write a program that queries it and then tells the graphics card to rotate the screen accordingly on Windows, the only reasons it probably hasn't been done is because the market for it isn't particularly large.

Comment: @waiwai933 That is incorrect. On Linux you will find plenty of support for this type of sensors in the OS in the form of the iio kernel subsystem.